# Change template dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have something like this

```
<script id="template1" type="text/html">
<h3>Template 1</h3>
<button id="templButton" data-bind="click: swap">Go to template 2</button>
</script>

<script id="template2" type="text/html">
<h3>Template 2</h3>
<button id="templButton" data-bind="click: swap">Go to template 2</button>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: theTemplate"></div>

<script>
ko.applyBindings({
    theTemplate: ko.observable("template1"),
    swap: function () {
        this.theTemplate("template2");
    }
});
</script>
```

But it change template only one time and only from `tempalate1` to the `template2`. How to make switch to the both templates.

it shoudl be something like

```
ko.applyBindings({
        theTemplate: ko.observable("template1"),
        swap: function () {
            if (this.theTemplate==template1)
            {
                this.theTemplate("template2");
            }
            else
            {
                this.theTemplate("template1");
            }
        }
    });
```

But what is `this.theTemplate("template2")` what operation `()` making in current context? How to check in what state is `theTemplate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a couple things:

1. To get the value of an observable, you invoke it
2. The value of the observable is a string, so quote it

So:

```
    if (this.theTemplate() == 'template1') {
```

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  theTemplate: ko.observable("template1"),
  swap: function() {
    if (this.theTemplate() == 'template1') {
      this.theTemplate("template2");
    } else {
      this.theTemplate("template1");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script id="template1" type="text/html">
  <h3>Template 1</h3>
  <button id="templButton" data-bind="click: swap">Go to template 2</button>
</script>

<script id="template2" type="text/html">
  <h3>Template 2</h3>
  <button id="templButton" data-bind="click: swap">Go to template 2</button>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: theTemplate"></div>
```